# How do I check that the left click button is actively being held down?

Tags: python, keyboard, mouse

I want to move my mouse down 10 pixels every time that my left click is held in.

```
import keyboard
import mouse

keyboard.wait('-')

while mouse.click('left') == True:
    mouse.move(0, 100, absolute=False, duration=0.2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using libraries such as `pyautogui` and `pynput` like so:

```
from pynput.mouse import Listener
import pyautogui

x,y = pyautogui.position()

def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    if pressed:
        pyautogui.moveTo(x+10,y)
    
with Listener(on_click=on_click) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Comment: This solution has helped the cursor to move. However it only does so when I click left click and I can't figure out how to make it so that as I hold left click, the cursor moves down.